# Why does Ashcroft and Mermin say an acceptor level in a semiconductor cannot be empty, only singly or doubly occupied?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

On page 581 of Ashcroft and Mermin, Solid State Physics:

> ***Acceptor Level*** In contrast to a donor level, an acceptor level, when viewed as an
> electronic level, can be singly or doubly occupied, but not empty. This is easily seen
> from the hole point of view. An acceptor impurity can be regarded as a fixed, negatively
> charged attractive center superimposed on an unaltered host atom. This additional
> charge $-e$ can weakly bind one hole (corresponding to one electron being in the acceptor level). The binding energy of the hole is $\epsilon_a - \epsilon_v$, and when the hole is
> "ionized" an additional electron moves into the acceptor level. However, the con­figuration in which no electrons are in the acceptor level corresponds to two holes
> being localized in the presence of the acceptor impurity, which has a very high
> energy due to the mutual Coulomb repulsion of the holes.
>
> Bearing this in mind, we can calculate the mean number of electrons at an acceptor
> level from (28.30) by noting that the state with no electrons is now prohibited, while
> the two-electron state has an energy that is $\epsilon_a$ higher than the two one-electron states.
>
> Therefore
> $$
> \langle n\rangle
> =
> \frac{
> 2e^{\beta\mu} + 2e^{-\beta(\epsilon_a-2\mu)}
> }{
> 2e^{\beta\mu} + e^{-\beta(\epsilon_a-2\mu)}
> }
> \,.
> $$

In the quote, $\epsilon_a$ is the energy of the acceptor level, $\epsilon_v$ is the energy of the top of the valence band, and $\langle n\rangle$ is the average occupancy of the acceptor level. Equation (28.30) is
$$
\langle n\rangle
=
\frac{
\sum N_je^{-\beta(E_j- \mu N_j)}
}{
\sum e^{-\beta(E_j- \mu N_j)}
}
$$
where $E_j$ and $N_j$ are the energy and number of electrons in state $j$.

It seems like the two electron state corresponds to a situation where the acceptor ion has a full outer shell (hole filled), whereas the one electron state is when the hole is not filled. I'm not sure what the zero electron state refers to. Why can we not say then that the situation where the acceptor hole is filled is the single electron state?<sup>1</sup>

Also, if the acceptor level cannot be empty, at absolute zero is the Fermi level between $\epsilon_v$ and $\epsilon_a$? If so, would this not mean the acceptor level is empty?

---

<sup>1.</sup> Like the description on page 580 "The hole is bound when the level is empty."

Comment: Have you found the answer? I'm looking for it but can't see it.

Comment: @KarimChahine Unfortunately not. I don't really understand their physical motivation for calculating the average occupancy of the acceptor level in this manner. On page 580, they say "The hole is bound when the level is empty" as well, so I'm assuming perhaps they mean something else by "acceptor level" here than on pg. 580 (and in general, since I think all levels apart from the valence should be empty at zero temperature). Maybe "acceptor level" is a akin to an electron orbital (1 electron filled is the 1 hole state and 2 electron filled is the zero holes state).

Comment: It seems like you can equivalently do the $\langle n\rangle$ calculation by considering the acceptor level as capable of holding zero or one electron. The zero electron state corresponding to the one hole state, and the one electron state as the zero/filled hole state.

Comment: My reasoning for this is as follows. A semiconductor has N, say silicon, atoms. Impurities, say boron atoms, are added to the material. A single impurity is modeled as a -1 ion with a bound +ve hole orbiting around it, superimposed on the pure N atom silicon crystal with N standing wave electrons. If the bound hole is ionised, gaining an energy of $\epsilon_a - \epsilon_v$, and becomes effectively a free particle, then presumably one of the N electrons loses an energy $\epsilon_a - \epsilon_v$ and drops into a different state, which we identify as the acceptor level.

Comment: I seem the get the same answer doing it this way, but whether this physical interpretation of the mathematics of the band theory as a whole is accurate, I'm not sure and haven't put that much thought about it.

Comment: Or maybe a hole gaining $\epsilon_a - \epsilon_v$ energy is the same as some other electron gaining $\epsilon_a - \epsilon_v$ energy, idk. Just sharing thoughts.

Comment: @KarimChahine I haven't got the time to work out the details exactly and write an answer, but I think I figured it out. So I think in Chapter 12 of the semiclassical model, it's derived that we can consider hole dynamics equivalently to electron dynamics. The valence electron states/levels of the ion lattice were found by considering single electron states (whether through nearly free approx or tight binding). We then monkey patch 2 d.o.f to each level to form a basis for the multi electron system (antisymmetric product of the single electron wavefunctions).

Comment: View the donor as a negative ion in a homogeneous semiconductor with one electron removed from the valence, or equivalently a system with one hole in the valence. This hole represents the lack of an electron in one of the levels, which we said holds two electrons. So a level with one hole, is a level with one electron. A level with zero holes, is a level with two electrons.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: As for the fermi level business, I suppose this means the fermi level has to be equal to the acceptor level $\epsilon_a$? kind of drawing a line through the degeneracy. Or realistically there would be some splitting due to spin interactions.

Answer (score 0):

One should remember that each energy level has two spin states. You are right in that "two electron state corresponds to a situation where the acceptor ion has a full outer shell (hole filled), whereas the one electron state is when the hole is not filled". That one electron is assumed to be occupying the corresponding bound energy state. Every such energy state can accommodate two electrons with different spins.

Having two holes attached to the acceptor impurity is energetically unfavorable, similarly to how it is unfavorable to  have two electrons on the same donor site: the negative ion is shielded by the first hole (which is assumed to be already there) and the second hole is not going to be attracted to the impurity strongly enough to form a bound state (this is a bit too handwavy argument to my taste, but I am quite sure this is what Ashcroft and Mermin mean).

The equation for the mean number of particles $\langle n\rangle$ is obtained from the assumption that there are two one-particle states and a single two-particle state.

Comment: Why does the electron occupy the bound energy state in the one electron state? And what do you think the answer is for OP's last question?

Comment: Think of acceptors inside a semiconductor as kind of halogens atoms in vacuum. And think of donor atoms inside a semiconductor as an alkali metal in vacuum. In other words acceptors behave similarly to fluorine and donors behave similarly to sodium. Fluorine does not like to be positively charged and sodium does not like to be negatively charged. Conventionally, we call a neutral state of a donor/acceptor to have one electron, positively charged state - zero electrons and negatively charged state - two electrons

Comment: As fluorine doesn't like to be positively charged, acceptors do not like either. Similarly, as sodium does not like to be negatively charged, donors do not like either. It is a long story why sodium and fluorine behave this way, but it all comes from interplay between filled energy shells and charge shielding.

Comment: Fermi distribution is a distribution for non-interacting electrons and it doesn't work as intuitively or cleanly for interacting systems, where placing electron in one level influences positions of all other levels. It is easier to do arguments from the more basic energy considerations